# socket io Emit functin executes irrespective of call

Tags: socket.io

in below code there is post middleware which is for like and dislike. and emitDislike and emit Like are socket.io Emit functions. when i like are dislike of particular post it updates in data base and also showes the updatedLike to all the users.

but the Problem is even the post have a  middleware "/liked/:itemId/:type" which only executes the for the particular post Id which is liked or disliked. but emit functions in post middleware excutes for every post when i liked or disliked.

for example there are 20 posts and and haveing a like for every post, so there are total 20 likes. if i liked one particular post, the emit function calls 20 times for each and every post

> post MiddleWare

```
router.post("/liked/:itemId/:type", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let { itemId, type } = req.params;
    let userId = req.session.userId.toString();
    let item;
    if (type === "post") item = await Post.findById(itemId);
    else if (type == "comment") item = await Comment.findById(itemId);
    else return res.json({ mssg: "Invalid Item Type" });

    let itemWithLike = await item.populate("like");
    let like = itemWithLike.like;
    let liked = like.users.includes(userId);

    if (liked) {
      let index = like.users.indexOf(userId);
      like.users.splice(index, 1);
      like.likes--;
      Io.emitDislike();
    } else {
      like.users.push(userId.toString());
      Io.emitLike();
      like.likes++;
    }
    await like.save();
    res.json(like);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});
```

> socket.js

```
let io;
let socket;
module.exports = {
  init: (httpServer) =>
    (io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
      cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3001",
        methods: "GET POST",
      },
    })),
  connect: () =>
    io.on("connection", (s) => {
      socket = s;
    }),
  getIo: () => io,
  getSocket: () => socket,
  emitDislike: () => socket.broadcast.emit("get-likes", -1),
  emitLike: () => socket.broadcast.emit("get-likes", +1),
};
```